# Sql Server Ordenar hijos con padres

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo una funcion que me regresa la siguiente información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera ordenarla asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Order by Job? que intentaste que no funciono? porque en realidad hay job desordenados, cual es la logica del orden?

Comment: @gbianchi nop, más bien `ORDER BY ID, Assembly_Level` o `ORDER BY ID, Job`

Comment: Mira se supone que son ordenes de fabricación, aqui tengo una silla que tiene por materiales  un respaldo y patas que vendrían siendo los assembly_Level 0 y ese respaldo y pata a su vez son ordenes de fabricación y cada una de esas puede tener sus materiales y asi. no se si me doy a entender

Comment: no la verdad que no Jorge. Cual es la logica del orden?

Comment: @Lamak si ordenas asi, las 2 patas van a venir en cualquier orden...

Comment: @gbianchi mmm...no veo el porqué

Comment: mismo id mismo job, la db no asegura el orden de los registros internos...

Comment: Ese id yo lo genero en automático cuando creo la consulta, ya puse la consulta de como saco ese resultado

Comment: A ver.. la db sabe ordenar por 3 cosas.. numeros, letras o fechas.. (que en realidad son numeros internamente)... Si vos queres ordenar por otra logica distinta, tenes que enseñarle a la db (y a nosotros) como es ese orden...

Comment: @gbianchi por eso también puse que podría ordenar por el assembly_level

Comment: Ya puse como están los registros en la BD

Comment: pero si lo ordeno por assembly_level  no sale como en la imagen :(

Comment: @JorgeLuis por eso dije que el orden podría ser `ORDER BY ID, Assembly_Level`

Comment: El problema es que el id se genera con newid() y cada que se ejecuta puede cambiar el orden

Comment: Por eso.. Olvidate de ese campo. Si no estuviera ese campo, COMO seria el orden logico de esto? como le explicarias a un ser humano que ordenara esos datos, sin reglas de negocios. Que registro pongo antes, cual despues y porque?

Comment: mmm creo que sin ese id no sabria como, porque se tienen 2 tablas uno de Ordenes de trabajo y otro de materiales y un material también puede ser una orden de trabajo. una orden de trabajo tiene materiales que a su vez pueden ser ordenes dde trabajo y esa tener materiales y así. No se si el problema venga desde la consulta recursiva que muestro arriba

Comment: para que quede idéntico como indica el user el orden debería ser `ID DESC, Assembly_Level`. Aunque creo que todos compatibilizamos que ordenar por ese identificador único NO es la mejor manera.

Comment: Yo a todo esto sigo sin entender el orden. Jorge no logras explicar en palabras claras como ordenar los datos.

Comment: Con los datos que has indicado no hay forma de llegar al orden que estás mostrando en tu ejemplo. Revisa el caso de `GOMA-PATA | POLI` y `GOMA-PATA | PUMPS`, ¿de donde dónde sale el orden?

Comment: Hola ya hice modificaciones, ahora tengo una columna padre y una hijo tal vez así sea mas facil

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Necesitas crear una *ruta* para definir el orden que muestre a la estructura del árbol.
Es algo relativamente sencillo usando una columna binary.

```
WITH CTE
AS
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CAST(J.Assembly_Level AS INT) AS Assembly_Level,
        J.Job,
        J.Part_Number,
        MR.Material,
        MR.Quantity_Per,
        NEWID() AS ID,
        CAST( CAST(Material AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(4000)) AS Ruta
    FROM Job J
        LEFT JOIN Material_Req MR ON MR.Job = J.Job
        where j.job = '13466'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CAST(Job.Assembly_Level + J.Assembly_Level + 1 AS INT) AS Assembly_Level,
        Job.Job,
        Job.Part_Number,
        MR.Material,
        MR.Quantity_Per,
        j.ID,
        CAST(J.Ruta + CAST(MR.Material AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(4000)) AS Ruta
    FROM CTE J
      JOIN Job Job on Job.Part_Number = J.Material AND Job.Assembly_Level = 0
     JOIN Material_Req MR ON MR.Job = Job.Job)

    SELECT * FROM CTE
    ORDER BY Ruta;
```

Comment: Exacto muchas gracias :)

Comment: Agradecería si puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta.